# Why is `commitEditingStyle` of UITableViewDelegate required for editing to be enabled?

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm building an extremely basic note taking app and one of the features I wanted was to try to add slide to delete / share functionality.

Here's my current delegate implementation:

```
extension SomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("Selected indexpath: \(indexPath)")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Why does this have to be here? It doesn't do anything, it never gets called, and yet without it, the project won't run
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("Commit Editing Style \(editingStyle)")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> [AnyObject]! {

        var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Share", handler: {
            (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in
            println("Triggered share action \(action) atIndexPath: \(indexPath)")
            return
            })

        var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler: {
            (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in
            println("Triggered delete action \(action) atIndexPath: \(indexPath)")
            return
            })

        return [deleteAction, shareAction]
    }
}
```

**Note** 
I add the returns to the handler closures because in Swift, single line closures implicitly return that value as an argument and Beta 4 is throwing errors.  I only want to demonstrate the concept, so I don't need more than one line ...

**The Problem**

The function `commitEditingStyle` above never gets called, and I don't do anything in it.  However, if I remove it, the app no longer functions.

**With `commitEditingStyle` included**

[image: TableViewEditingWorking]

**With `commitEditingStyle` NOT included**

[image: TableViewEditingBroken]

**NOTE**

At the time of writing this question, I am running Xcode Beta 4 with its current simulator implementation.

**Edit**

There is also a thread about this in Objective-C [here.](https://gist.github.com/scheinem/e36835db07486e9f7e64)  If you read the comments, you'll see that there is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an implementation detail on Apple's part for how they implement UITableViews, but the assumption is that if you are going to display such buttons, you need a way to handle their actions which is what `commitEditingStyle` is for. Given what you have noticed, they probably check to see if you have implemented that selector (`respondsToSelector`), and if so, they create the views and animations to allow the slide to reveal more actions. This way, if the user clicks on a button, there won't be an exception of "unrecognized selector sent to instance" thrown.

Remember, the selector `commitEditingStyle` is @optional in the protocol definition, so you don't have to implement it. However, UITableView knows that if you don't have it, why should it display anything that might cause an exception later in the code.

Comment: I removed the handler closure arguments expecting to see my commit editing triggered, but instead the app crashed.  Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What code did you remove? Can you provide the new code and the crash message?